# Inconsistent accessibility error C#

Tags: c#, list, properties

I'm getting an error with a property for a list. It's saying the list is less accessible than the property.. I'm not sure why I am getting this error..

```
//List
private List<Client> clientList = new List<Client>();

//Property
public List<Client> ClientListAccessor
{
    get 
    { 
        return clientList; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        clientList = value; 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most probably `Client` is not a public class, and `ClientListAccessor` is publically accessible. The caller will have access to the property but wouldn't know the type it returns.

Answer (score 6):

That's happening, because the class `Client` is not defined as a `public` class. Make sure, the class definition looks like this:

```
public class Client
{
    // ...
}
```

In your code it probably looks like this:

```
class Client
{
    // ...
}
```

or like this (which is the same):

```
internal class Client
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, both solutions helped :)

Comment: Yes, you're right... my thought was correct (Client class was not public) but I wrote (too fast) in the wrong way. +1 for you. Thanks